# Python Regex search taking too long

Tags: python, regex

Following regex comparison is taking too long (> 2 mins).

```
re.search('^(\S+){2,50}/(\S+){2,50}\-trailing/$', 'test-request/this-is-crashing/')
```

Removing the length limits ({2-50}), solves the issue.

What is the error in the pattern?

env: Ubuntu i5 4GB Python 2.7.3

Comment: Did you try to use the same regex with(e.g) perl? Anyway, you do know what `(\S+){2,50}` means? Anyway, probably is some backtracking optimization issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(\S+){2,50}
```

Are you sure you need this? `\S+` means one or more occurrences. And then you want 2-50 occurrences of it?

Why not:

```
\S{2,50}
```

Comment: You are correct, this is called [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Answer (score 0):

why not make it much simpler...

```
re.match('([^/]+)/([^/]+)-trailing/', 'test-request/this-is-crashing/')
```

although in this case it does not find anything...

i suppose you want to catch only strings which are similar to this:

`'<SOME-TEXT>/<SOME-TEXT>-trailing/'`